# Pandas rolling sum that includes previous and coming days

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

A beginner, basically, trying to find a rolling sum that includes today, last 4 days, and coming days, in this case 1 next day (tomorrow).

```
            Test
1995-07-01    1 
1995-07-02    0 
1995-07-03    0 
1995-07-04    1    
1995-07-05    0    
1995-07-06    0    
1995-07-07    0    
1995-07-08    0    
1995-07-09    0    
1995-07-10    0    
1995-07-11    1
```

Got rolling sum of 'today' and past 4 days to work 
df['test'].rolling(5).sum()

```
1995-07-01    NaN
1995-07-02    NaN
1995-07-03    NaN
1995-07-04    NaN
1995-07-05    2.0
1995-07-06    1.0
1995-07-07    1.0
1995-07-08    1.0
1995-07-09    0.0
1995-07-10    0.0
1995-07-11    1.0
```

But including the next day's value into this sum is difficult for me, what I want is the output 1995-07-10 to show 1 since it needs to include 'tomorrow' (since 1995-07-11 is a 1 in the Test data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you need is the `shift()` method. It will allow you to shift your data by a number of days and then you can align it to the dates however you'd like.

[See this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) for documentation.

```
df['test'].shift(-1,fill_value=0).rolling(5).sum()
```

provides:

```
date
1995-07-01    NaN
1995-07-02    NaN
1995-07-03    NaN
1995-07-04    NaN
1995-07-05    1.0
1995-07-06    1.0
1995-07-07    1.0
1995-07-08    0.0
1995-07-09    0.0
1995-07-10    1.0
1995-07-11    1.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was simple and worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
pd.Series(df.Test.iloc[0]).append(df.Test.shift(-1)) \
                          .rolling(6, min_periods=1).sum().iloc[1:].astype(int)
```

resulting *(the original series is here only for a comfortable quick check)*

> ```
> --- Result ---                -- (Original) --
>
>            Test                           Test
> 1995-07-01    1               1995-07-01     1
> 1995-07-02    1               1995-07-02     0
> 1995-07-03    2               1995-07-03     0
> 1995-07-04    2               1995-07-04     1
> 1995-07-05    2               1995-07-05     0
> 1995-07-06    1               1995-07-06     0
> 1995-07-07    1               1995-07-07     0
> 1995-07-08    1               1995-07-08     0
> 1995-07-09    0               1995-07-09     0
> 1995-07-10    1               1995-07-10     0
> 1995-07-11    1               1995-07-11     1
> ```

---

**The explanation:**

1. We want to shift the `df.Test` series 1 position up to include the next day ("tomorrow") into a rolling window, but it has a bad consequence — the first member of the original series disappears.
2. So we save it (`df.Test.iloc[0]`) in the form of 1-element series (`pd.Series(df.Test.iloc[0])`).
3. Only then we perform the intended shift of the original series (`df.Test.shift(-1)`).
4. The resulting shifted series we append to previously saved 1-element series (`pd.Series(df.Test.iloc[0]).append(df.Test.shift(-1))`).
5. Now we are ready to create a rolling window with size of 6 (4 days ago + today + tomorrow) and with minimal period of 1 to prevent arising `NaN` values (`.rolling(6, min_periods=1)`).
6. The final steps are now obvious:

   - applying the `.sum()` method,
   - drop the first element (`.iloc[1:]`), which was prepended to the shifted series only for rolling window calculation,
   - possibly convert the data type of the resulting series back to the integer type (`.astype(int)`)

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Tomorrow'] = df.shift(-1)
df['Previous'] = df['Test'].rolling(4).sum()
df.sum(axis=1)

Output

1995-07-01    1.0
1995-07-02    0.0
1995-07-03    1.0
1995-07-04    3.0
1995-07-05    1.0
1995-07-06    1.0
1995-07-07    1.0
1995-07-08    0.0
1995-07-09    0.0
1995-07-10    1.0
1995-07-11    2.0
```

Or if you like the first 3 rows to have a value for previous 4 even if there were fewer than 4 days:

```
df['Previous'] = df['Test'].rolling(4, min_periods=1).sum()
```